# why i get this error open("./cgi_plugin.so"): No such file or directory?

Tags: python, cgi, uwsgi

i have installed uwsgi:

```
curl http://uwsgi.it/install | bash -s cgi /usr/bin/uwsgi
```

than instaled CGI plugin:

```
curl http://uwsgi.it/install | bash -s cgi /tmp/uwsgi
python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/cgi
```

and when i run my uwgi_config.ini

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = cgi
socket = 127.0.0.1:9010
cgi = /=/cgi-bin
cgi-allowed-ext = .py
cgi-helper = .py=python
```

> uwsgi --http :9011 --http-modifier1 9 --ini uwsgi_config.ini --master

i have error:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi_config.ini
open("./cgi_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3675]
```

Comment: Why would you install uwsgi then want to run Python scripts through it via CGI? Use a proper WSGI application.

Comment: Just a remark: even if I also get the same error, uwsgi works and I get my script executed and served ;)